# How to select a column where other columns have specific values

Tags: sqlite

Can I do something like this

> SELECT Actors FROM Movies WHERE Genre, ReleaseDate = SciFi, 1994

I want all actors that are in SciFi movies released in 1994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off.  Use this:

```
SELECT Actors
FROM Movies
WHERE Genre = 'SciFi' AND
      ReleaseDate = 1994
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite 3.15.0 or later, you can use [row values](http://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html):

```
SELECT Actors
FROM Movies
WHERE (Genre, ReleaseDate) = ('SciFi', 1994);
```